# How can I differentiate the routes before navigate?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have an Angular 4 application. In the application I have 2 main entities - category and product. The problem is that my entities have a very similar structure of the route (/:category_id, /:product_id). I can't change structure of the route because of SEO issues. So my question is - how can I organize my routes in this situation? Maybe I should use Resolvers, or pass some meta information about requested data from backend to parse it in Angular?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can make your routes look like `category/:category_id` and `product/:product_id` for category and products

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but as I said above, I can't change the structure of the URL. Unfortunately, I can't add the "category" or "product" segment to my URLs

Comment: the main problem I see is that both routes send you to the same component. I supouse your component have Two childrens:app-category and app-product. So you must, before router to the page, "save", what you will see. you can use a service to store in a variable if is a component or a product and use *ngIf to show one or another children, but I'm not sure if is the best solution